# Does multi threaded system affect the accuracy of delay counting

Tags: c#, windows

In Windows (assuming a quad core processor is being used), there are 4 high priority threads running in parallel currently.

I have to execute a simple application which just counts for every X/2 ms. Where 'X' is the least time in ms used for thread context switch.

In this case, the count which is being updated will not accurately tells how many X/2 ms elapsed.

Is that right?

Comment: I'ms scared, can you please explain this a bit more. what are you counting and how

Comment: This is not a real project. Just wanted to clarify. The count is nothing just incremented once in every X/2 ms.

Comment: Hard to guess what else you expected to happen.  You have a clock that keeps accurately track of real elapsed time, DateTime.UtcNow.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is incrementing a variable is not *Thread Safe*, you will have to lock it somehow, otherwise threads running on diffrent cpus will be constantly be out of date with the latest counter value.

The best way to do this is with some sort of locking mechanism, for example `lock`. However this will have some overhead, and wont give you the true max performance.

If you want to get as close as possible consider using a better locking mechanism that `lock` for example :

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref myNum);
```

[Interlocked.Increment Method (Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Increments a specified variable and stores the result, as an atomic
>   operation.

`Increment` basically turns into a "bus lock" statement. This statement locks the bus to prevent another *CPU* from accessing the bus while the calling *CPU* does its operation

However its best to look at all the Interlocked methods to see the various atomic operations available and to find those that suit your needs. Use `lock()` when you want to do more complex things like multiple inter-related increments/decrements, or to serialize access to resources that are more complex than integers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So that I should make a dedicated thread safe code with lock() statement to achieve this.

Comment: `lock` will be slower then `Interlocked.Increment(ref myNum);` but year to make it thread safe or to get sensical values out of your count you will need to make it thread sage somehow

Comment: I believe there is no way to dedicate a CPU core for the process I intended programmatically. There is an option to increase thread priority to higher level. But still will get interrupted by hardware interrupts. So in windows it is not easy to make it as like in real time systems.

Comment: Its hard to know what you are trying to do. but in short, keeping a counter in a multi threaded environment is not thread safe

Comment: @Jebakumar if this has helped you make sure you upvote and mark it as correct, or if you found another solution consider adding your own answer and marking it correct so you can help future readers